# Oracle 11g SQL: Pivot Table -- Variable number of columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot

I am trying to take a table and pivot the values of two columns to their own columns. The twist is that there can be variable numbers of entries per anchor. Here is a toy table:

```
    CREATE TABLE ATTRS
    ( WIDGET VARCHAR2(15), 
      A_NAME VARCHAR2(15), 
      A_VALUE VARCHAR2(15)
     );
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('BOOK','PAGES','1000');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('BOOK','COLOR','GREEN');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('BOOK','LAST','TWAIN');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('BOOK','FIRST','MARK');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('CELLPHONE','BRAND','SAMSUNG');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('LAPTOP','BRAND','LENOVO');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('LAPTOP','COLOR','BLACK');
    INSERT INTO ATTRS VALUES ('LAPTOP','BATTERY','STANDARD');
```

I will know the maximum number of unique A_NAME that can occur (we'll let it be 4 in this example) and want output like this:

```
    WIDGET    | A_NAME1 | A_VALUE1 | A_NAME2 | A_VALUE2 | A_NAME3 | A_VALUE3   | A_NAME4 | A_VALUE4
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    BOOK      | PAGES   | '1000'   | COLOR   | 'GREEN'  | LAST    | 'TWAIN'    | FIRST   | 'MARK'
    CELLPHONE | BRAND   | 'SAMSUNG'| (null)  | (null)   | (null)  | (null)     | (null)  | (null) 
    LAPTOP    | COLOR   | 'BLACK'  | BRAND   | 'LENOVO' | BATTERY | 'STANDARD' | (null)  | (null)
```

Note that order does not matter, i.e. if two A_NAME are the same, they need *not* be in the same column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd have to think for a minute about how to accomplish this with the new (in 11g) `pivot` operator.  Knowing that there are at most 4 rows per `widget`, though, you can do an old-school pivot along the lines of

```
SELECT widget,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a_name ELSE NULL END) a_name1,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN a_value ELSE NULL END) a_value1,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a_name ELSE NULL END) a_name2,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN a_value ELSE NULL END) a_value2,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a_name ELSE NULL END) a_name3,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN a_value ELSE NULL END) a_value3,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN a_name ELSE NULL END) a_name4,
       max(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN a_value ELSE NULL END) a_value4
  FROM( SELECT widget,
               a_name,
               a_value,
               row_number() over (partition by widget 
                                      order by a_name, a_value) rn
          FROM attrs )
 GROUP BY widget
```

Comment: Thanks! That'll work for now, I would be interested to see how you could accomplish it with PIVOT if you do ever come up with it.